# Users don't load Sitefinity

Tags: asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0, telerik, sitefinity

I'm having an issue with SitefinityMembershipProvider in Sitefinity 9.1

When I login to the backend, navigate to Administration -> Users:Page keeps loading.
When I checked the error log it tells me that **"Provider must implement the class 'System.Web.Security.MembershipProvider"**.

But my class inherits sitefinity membership provider i.e. MembershipDataProvider
which is of type Telerik.Sitefinity.Security.Data.

My web config have the following membership defined.

```
<membership defaultProvider="Default">
    <providers>
        <clear />
        <add name="Default" type="Telerik.Sitefinity.Security.Data.SitefinityMembershipProvider, Telerik.Sitefinity" />
        <add name="CredentialServiceProvider" type="SitefinityWebApp.Providers.CredentialServiceProvider" />
    </providers>
```

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?  Because I'm now having the same issue with Sitefinity 10.

Answer (score 0):

You need to register the provider in the Security settings as explained here:

http://docs.sitefinity.com/custom-membership-provider-add-the-new-provider-to-the-sitefinity-providers-collection

Comment: I had done it and the name of the Membership provider is CredentialServiceProvider,

Answer (score 0):

Additionally, I had to remove the custom provider from the web.config

```
<providers>
    <clear />
    <add name="Default" type="Telerik.Sitefinity.Security.Data.SitefinityMembershipProvider, Telerik.Sitefinity" />
</providers>
```